# Prove that $(\ln(2t))^2 \leqslant2t\ln 2 $ for all $t\geqslant2$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> Prove that $\;(\ln(2t))^2\leqslant2t\ln 2\;\;$ for all $\;t\geqslant2\,.$

I am able to prove that $\,\ln 2t\leqslant t\ln 2\,.$ But I am not able to prove the required inequality. I have tried Mean value theorem too. Any help or hint would be appreciable.

Edits for the proof of $\,\ln 2t\leqslant t\ln 2\,$.

We have $t\leq 2^{t-1}$ for $t\geq 2$. So, $2t\leq 2^t$. So $\ln 2t\leq t\ln 2$

Comment: @Angelo: Re your edits: Shouldn't it be a decision of the *author* whether to use $\le $ or $\leqslant$? (I, for example, always use the former.) I am also not sure if inserting a small space before and after inline formulas is an improvement.

Comment: Madhan, it would be desirable to add more context to your question. You should write your proof of the inequality $\ln 2t\leqslant  t\ln2$.

Comment: How did you show the simpler inequality? Can you show your work? Can you use derivatives?

Comment: @MartinR, you are right. If the original poster prefers to use “$\leq$” instead of “$\leqslant$”, he will modify his post just as he likes. But it was necessary to edit it because he had not written what he wanted to prove apart from the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use the inequality that you proved, $\ln 2t \leq t\ln 2$ for $t\geq 2$. If we divide both sides by $t$, and integrate from $2$ to $x\geq 2$, we obtain
\begin{align}
&\int_2^x \frac{\ln2t}{t}\,dt\leq\int_2^x \ln 2\,dt \\
&\qquad\implies\frac{1}{2}\left.(\ln 2t)^2\right|_2^x \leq \left. t\ln 2\right|_2^x \\
&\qquad\implies \frac{1}{2}(\ln 2x)^2-\frac{1}{2}(\ln 4)^2 \leq (x-2)\ln 2 \\
&\qquad\implies(\ln 2x)^2\leq 2x\ln 2 + (\ln 4)^2-4\ln 2\leq 2x\ln 2\qquad(x\geq 2), 
\end{align}
since $(\ln 4)^2-4\ln 2=(2\ln 2)^2-4\ln 2 = 4\ln 2\,(\ln 2-1)<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the derivative of $f(x) := \frac{\ln^2 x}{x}$ which is $\frac{(2-\ln(x))\ln x}{x^2}$ by quotient rule. It has a root at $x=e^2$ and $x=1$. This means $f(x)$ is an increasing function when $1<x<e^2$ and decreasing when $x\in (0,1) \cup (e^2, \infty)$.

You can hence verify that the maximum value of $f(x)$ for $x \in [1, \infty)$ is attained at $x=e^2$. But, $f(e^2) = \frac{4}{e^2} <\ln2$. Hence we have proven your (inequality) claim for not just $t\geq 2$ but $t \geq \frac{1}{2}$.

Regarding the equality: in fact, we have already shown that equality can not be attained when $t \geq \frac{1}{2}$. However we do know that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = +\infty$ so there does in fact exist an equality case but that's only in $t \in (0,\frac{1}{2})$

Answer (score 1):

By $t=\frac{e^{x}}{2}$ with $x\ge \ln 4$ we obtain

$$(\ln(2t))^2 \leqslant2t\ln 2 \iff g(x)=e^x\ln 2 -x^2\ge 0$$

with

- $g(\ln 4)>0$
- $g'(x)= e^x\ln 2-2x\ge 0$ for $x\ge \ln 4$
- $g''(x)= e^x\ln 2-2>0$ for $x>\ln\left(\frac2{\ln 2}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Using the well-known inequality $\ln(y) \le y-1$ we get for all $x > 0$
$$
 \ln x = 2 \ln \sqrt x = 2 \left( 1 + \ln \frac{\sqrt x}{e}\right)
\le \frac{2}{e}  \sqrt x \, .
$$
If $x \ge 1$ then $\ln x \ge 0$ and we can square the inequality:
$$
 (\ln x)^2 \le \frac{4}{e^2} x
$$
which is better than the desired inequality since $4/e^2 < \ln 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(t)=\ln(2t)-\sqrt{2t\ln2}$. Since $f(2)$ is negative, it is enough to show that $f(t)$ is decreasing for $t\geq2.$ Now,
$$f'(t)=\frac1t-\frac{\sqrt{\ln2}}{\sqrt t}$$
is negative for $t>\frac1{\ln2}\approx\frac1{\color{red}{0.69}}.$ We are done.